# Update postgres view over Spring boot project

Tags: spring, postgresql, view

I have two database one of them for development environment and the other for prod env. My problem occur when I modify one of the views at development database. I have to apply this change to production environment. I have already searched database migration tools, however I think these tools don't log directly change in database.
I can solve this problem add all views to spring startup sql and update this sql every change in the view. However this solution is also prone to mistakes.
Is there any efficient way to this problem?

Comment: Liquibase can be integrated into Spring

Comment: Liquibase or Flyway can do that. Examples: https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway, https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/springboot.html

Comment: I searched Liquibase or Flyway but I'm not sure about these tools log any of modification at sql codes. I think examples generally focus on spring side modifications